# How can I check that program was installed successfully on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bin

I have .bin file, that contains a lot of scripts, that install program on Ubuntu and after installing via terminal

```
sudo chmod u+x myprogram.bin
./myprogram
```

I have it in /usr/bin/myprogram.

I need to write the program, which checks if some program was installed correctly to the system. How can I do that ?

Comment: You need to define what exactly "installed successfully" means for your particular program (some programs require more than their executable to be usable, e.g. fonts or configuration files).

Comment: BTW, `/usr/bin/myprogram` is likely to accept some `--help` and/or `--version` program option per [GNU standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

Any one of the followings should work

```
$ command -v foo >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "installed" || echo "not installed"

$ type foo >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "installed" || echo "not installed"

$ hash foo >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "installed" || echo "not installed"
```

In your case you may use

```
$ command -v /usr/bin/myprogram >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "installed" || echo "not installed"
```

or else you can create function like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

installed()
{
  command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

# and then
if installed ls; then
     echo 'ls exists'
else
     echo 'ls not installed'
fi
```

Examples :

```
$ command -v ls >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "installed" || echo "not installed" 
installed

$ command -v foo >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "installed" || echo "not installed" 
not installed
```

**If you already know the full path to the application/program then any one of the following should work**

```
$ test -x /bin/ls && echo 'installed' || echo 'not installed'
installed

$ [ -x /bin/ls ] && echo 'installed' || echo 'not installed'
installed
```